# Test on Vaadin with testbench

Tags: java, vaadin, test-bench

I Trying to test my app with vaadin testbench but when I try to run my test with

mvn clean verify he don`t start my server to execute the tests, I using this sample: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/testbench/testBench-tutorial.html  and this is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.lumera</groupId>
    <artifactId>integra</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>integra</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <vaadin.version>7.7.0</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <vaadin.testbench.version>4.1.0.alpha2</vaadin.testbench.version>
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.9.v20160517</jetty.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- If there are no local customisations, this can also be "fetch" or 
            "cdn" -->
        <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/styles.css</include>
                                <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by 
                running jetty:run on the command line. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench-api</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>ckeditor-wrapper-for-vaadin</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
            <artifactId>easyuploads</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-grid-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.steinwedel.vaadin.addon</groupId>
            <artifactId>messagebox</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.alpha2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-combobox-multiselect</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
            <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-addons</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

But I have noted that when start my server before run tests, my test pass, but after run the tests he tried to start my server

I Put the original start/stop jetty

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

but don`t work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any Jetty configuration described in the "Start the Server Automatically" section of the linked document. The start and stop goals which are there tied to the pre-integration-test/post-integration-test phase will take care of starting the server before integration tests are run and stopping it afterwards.

Finally you need to ensure that your test is run in the integration test phase and not in the unit test phase. If they are run in the unit test phase, the pre-integration-test phase has not yet been executed and the server has not been started. Name your test SomethingIT.java (not SomethingTest.java) to ensure that it is run in the integration test phase.

Comment: I update the question, I put the original start/stop jetty, I trying to run with mvn clean verify (just site says) And if I run mvn jetty:run the server start normally

Comment: I still can't see the pre-integration-test/post-integration-test part in your pom.xml, so the server will not be started automatically